# Eclipse Makegood PHPUnit repository can't read

Tags: php, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pdt, makegood

I've been trying to install Makegood in Eclipse juno.

But I can't read the repository for Makegood.
it shows an error in eclipse like

> Unable to read repository at http://eclipse.piece-framework.com.
>   http://eclipse.piece-framework.com is not a valid repository location.

When Im trying to access the URL in browser it returns a forbidden message.

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access / on this server
>   Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at eclipse.piece-framework.com Port 80

Is there any other locations available for Makegood for PHPUnit testing on Eclipse juno?

Answer (score 0):

You must copy this link and paste in Eclipse>Help>Install new software>Add...>

Name: EclipsePieceFramework (or anything)

Location: http://eclipse.piece-framework.com

And then select your new worksite (EclipsePieceFramework (or anything)) and check MakeGood.
[http://piece-framework.com/projects/25/wiki/MakeGood_User_Guide_1_3_0#MakeGood-User-Guide](http://piece-framework.com/projects/25/wiki/MakeGood%5fUser%5fGuide%5f1%5f3%5f0#MakeGood-User-Guide)